# How to refresh java changes in xpages

Tags: java, xpages, refresh

I am developing an application on xpages, with Domino version 9.0.1 FP8. This is the first application in which I have developed a call to java classes through a one-button SSJS event. But specifically I am consuming a web service using the technique presented in the [article](http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2014/calling-web-services-from-xpages). What I noticed is that every time I change something that has a direct relationship with java, such as the java classes created and stored in the java folder of the designer or in the call of the web service method inside the SSJS event, an error is listed below . The only way to solve the problem, at least until now is to restart the Domino server. It's no use clearing the project, rebuilding it, and restarting http.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Is there any command on the Domino server that reflects this change? Is there any parameter in the application that I have to configure?

As we can see from the error below, it seems that it does not find the web service client classes that are located in a jar in the application jar folder.

```
HTTP JVM: java.lang.NullPointerException
HTTP JVM:   at   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.getResource(ModuleClassLoader.java:206)
```

Comment: When you restart http do you use `tell http restart` or `res task http`.  `res task http` should work.

Comment: Resolved with the comed 'res task http'. Grateful! But is there no application-level feature that does the same? Otherwise, I'll have to keep asking the administrator for every change, which is impractical.

Comment: That's why you should use your own development Domino server. You can install it on your local computer.

Comment: Here in the company we work in the classic way, that is to say, we have a corporate development server, where we do not have access to the administrative part. Installing a Domino server on every Domino developer machine is impractical.

Comment: It is impractical to ask the admin for an http restart every time. If several developers need a restart the same development server from time to time you can imagine how impractically this is: during backend debugging of one developer http task gets restarted because of a second developer... just saying. Web development ist different to classic Notes development and might need some adjustment of development process.

Comment: Just to expand on Knut's point, web development also requires server-side debugging. Only one developer can debug at any one time. And if developer A leaves a breakpoint in his code for a page, developer B starts debugging, developer A tests his page - developer A's browser freezes, developer B's client starts debugging something he's not expecting, both are confused and frustrated. Plugin development regularly requires a restart of HTTP. With a shared server, you also cannot load plugins directly from Eclipse, for every change you need to package an update site and deploy, then restart HTTP.

Comment: As a workaround you can rename the jar file when you make changes to it, import the renamed jar file and delete the old jar file. This way Domino will see the changes in the jar file

Comment: I agree in part with you. But is there no way IBM can develop a way to make this code change be reflected in the application-level java code. On other development platforms this is possible.

Comment: I am using the rename trick whenever I make changes to code assembled in a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your specific issue, issue `res task http` at the console. There are other workarounds posted in the comments to the main question that may be more practical for your situation though.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can rename the jar file when you make changes to it, import the renamed jar file and delete the old jar file. This way Domino will see the changes in the jar file.

I am using the rename trick whenever I make changes to code assembled in a jar file.

Comment: But will this work, as part of the java code is in classes in the java folder of the viewed application?

Comment: Yes. Code in the Java folder of your application will be able to use code from jar files no matter what their file name is